# HREF to call a PHP function and pass a variable?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to create an `HREF` link that calls a PHP function and passes a variable along with it?

```
<?php
function sample(){
    foreach ($json_output->object ){
        $name = "{$object->title}";
        $id = "{$object->id}";

        print "<a href='search($id)' >$name</a>";
    }
}

function search($id){
    //run a search via the id provide by the clicking of that particular name link
}
?>
```

Comment: It's possible to use AJAX from your HTML link to call a PHP script, passing in a value and returning something, but what you have there won't work.

Comment: @Revent if I put an input and submit button on each link would it work?

Comment: Probably not the way you're thinking of. There is **no way** to call a PHP function without sending another request to the server.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to do something without reloading the page? Or are you just trying to have a link submit to another page while passing an id value?

Comment: @Revent have a link submit to another page basically

Comment: Then follow some of the answers below like the one from @janenz00 that passes to another PHP script with the id as a query parameter.

Comment: Use AJAX call on your html link onclick event . This ajax will call a PHP page and you can do your desired functionality

Answer (score 14):

You can do this easily without using a framework. By default, anything that comes after a ? in a URL is a GET variable.

So for example, www.google.com/search.html?term=blah

Would go to www.google.com/search.html, and would pass the GET variable "term" with the value "blah".

Multiple variables can be separated with a &

So for example, www.google.com/search.html?term=blah&term2=cool

The GET method is independent of PHP, and is part of the HTTP specification.

PHP handles GET requests easily by automatically creating the superglobal variable $_GET[], where each array index is a GET variable name and the value of the array index is the value of the variable.

Here is some demo code to show how this works:

```
<?php
    //check if the get variable exists
    if (isset($_GET['search']))
    {
        search($_GET['search']);
    }

    function Search($res)
    {
        //real search code goes here
        echo $res;
    }


?>

<a href="?search=15">Search</a>
```

which will print out 15 because it is the value of search and my search dummy function just prints out any result it gets

Answer (score 3):

The HTML output needs to look like

```
<a href="php_file.php?id=1">anchor text</a>
```

Your function will need to output this information within that format.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do it directly. You can only link to a URL.

In this case, you can pass the function name and parameter in the query string and then handle it in PHP as shown below:

```
  print "<a href='yourphpscript.php?fn=search&id=$id' >$name</a>";
```

And, in the PHP code :

```
  if ($_GET['fn'] == "search")
     if (!empty($_GET['id']))
            search($id);
```

Make sure that you sanitize the GET parameters.

Comment: Does 'yourphpscript.php' need to refer to the same php page as the print statement outputting the link?  Does it need to be on a different page?  Doesn't matter?

Comment: It can be the same page, or a different one. Doesn't matter

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I tried using a different page, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not directly.

1. You can link to a URL
2. You can include data in the query string of that URL (`<a href="myProgram.php?foo=bar">`)
3. That URL can be handled by a PHP program
4. That PHP program can call a function as the only thing it does
5. You can pass data from `$_GET['foo']` to that function

Comment: if I put an input and submit button on each link would it work?

Comment: No. You could use a form with a submit button *instead of a link* (and then change step 1 of the answer to "You can submit a form to a URL") but you cannot place a button inside a link (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Example:

**From your view:**

```
    <p><a href="test/1" class="btn blue">Edit</a>
```

Where 1 is a parameter you want to send. It can be a data taken from an object too.

**From your controller:**

```
function test($id){
  #code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<?php
function sample(){
    foreach ($json_output->object ){
        $name = "{$object->title}";
        $id = "{$object->id}";

        print "<a href='?search=" . $id . "' > " . $name . "</a>";
    }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {
    search($_REQUEST['search']);
}

function search($id){
    //run a search via the id provide by the clicking of that particular name link
}
?>
```

Also make sure that your `$json_output` is accessible with is the `sample()` function. 
 You can do it either way

```
<?php
function sample(){
    global $json_output;
    // rest of the code
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
function sample($json_output){
    // rest of the code
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set query string in your link's `href` with the value and access it with `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['search']) ) {
        search( $_REQUEST['search'] );
    }

    function Search($res) {
        // search here
    }

    echo "<a href='?search='" . $id . "'>" . $name . "</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible, but you need an MVC type structure, and `.htaccess` URL rewriting turned on as well.

Here's some reading material to get you started in understanding what MVC is all about.

```
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html
```

And if you want to choose a sweet framework, instead of reinventing the MVC wheel, I highly suggest, [LARAVEL 4](http://laravel.com/)

Comment: Why the downvote?? This is a legit an answer as any.  Its true....if the OP wants a bunch of functions and those functions to be 'pages' that can be called, then MVC is the way to go about it

Comment: MVC is way too complicated for what OP is trying to do. Just learn a little AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is too complicated for what the OP has asked for

Comment: You don't need MVC or URL rewriting for this. Using it (as the question stands right now) would be a stupid level of overengineering. While some MVC frameworks have prewritten code to map URLs onto functions, you can do it yourself (without going near MVC) with far less overhead.

Comment: You can never call a PHP "function" from an "href", period. With or without MVC.

Comment: @deceze while that is 'true', and I do understand what you're saying....it really just is semantics.  WIth MVC you map the routes/names to the functions....how is that different from 'a href calling a function'  whether its through a rewrite module/router or not??

Comment: Then why do you "need" MVC if it's all arbitrary anyway?